# AppResource items not accessible although they are available

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App I use AppResources.de.resx and AppResources.resx

I can access resource constants in Code-Behind via `AppResources.CancelButtonText`.

Unfortunately, some of the constants are not accessible via AppResources and do not show up and raise an Error when used:

*'AppResources' does not contain a definition for 'ManageItem_DeleteMessage_UsedInSavedItems'*

I don't get why, since these constants are definitively available and I copied and pasted the string. They don't show up in IntelliSense and don't compile successfully when used.

I still can access it as a string in LanguageResourceManager["..."].

Tried by clearing my caches, too. Did not help.

**=== Update of my Resource Files ===**

There is a default AppResources.resx - both have the same set of constants

[image]

**=== Update after generating a new AppResources.resx file ===**

Seems like the naming now is totally screwed, but seems to be working anyway:

I added a new AppResource**s**.resx file (with an 's'). But the Designer File is without 's':

[image]

The section in my .csproj looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a default Resource like AppResources.resx

Comment: I updated my original question with the corresponding Screenshot

Comment: Aha, you have been copying the files. The designer is not associated with the default. You need to make the default from scratch. Add a new one.

Comment: Interesting that the AppResource.Designer.cs contains almost all of my constants, but some are missing. What about just adding the missing properties for the constants that are missing there? Or I create a new AppResource.resx file and rename the existing one to AppResource.en.resx or what are the correct steps to bring that in sync /fix?

Comment: Like Peter pointed out already, there may be a broken designer file association. You could fix that by updating the *.csproj* file of your app project. For that, we'll need to see what it looks like at the moment (only the bits related to the *.resx* files). Otherwise, you can also save the contents of the *AppResources.[lang].resx* files and recreate them from scratch and then re-add the contents.

Comment: I updated my question with the information after adding a new AppResources.resx file. I just copied the content from the original to this one. Right now, it seems to be working. Naming of the .designer-File changed a bit

Comment: @PeterWessberg - I think your response helped me in the first place. If you write a response, I will accept it as answer :) Also thank you Julian for your helpful comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image show that the default resource file and the designer file is not associated. When a default resuource file is created it automatic creates a associated extention file called `Designer.cs`. It helps accessing the resources by key.

If you copy resource files from another project this could typical happened.

The easiest way is to create new one and copy the fields from the original.

Read more about Localization files and how they work [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/localization?view=net-maui-8.0#create-resource-files-to-store-strings)